# how can I convert a Powerpoint presentation to a video file (AVI or WMV)?

Tags: video, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, avi, wmv

What tools can convert Powerpoint presentations to video formats?

Free (as in beer or as in speech) preferred, since this is a one-time thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of PowerPoint have this feature built into them. For example, with PowerPoint 2010, you can directly save a presentation as an WMV file.

Go to **File > Save & Send > Create a Video** and then click **Create a Video**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can save the slides as images (File -> Save as -> select suitable image file format in the file formats list), and then use Windows Movie Maker to make an avi or wmv file of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Techsmith's [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/accessories/powerpoint.asp) can record the whole of a Microsoft Pwerpoint presentation, including voice narration. Not a free product but a fully-functional limited-time trial version is available to allow evaluation before purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have access to the Mac version of powerpoint, you can go file, save as movie and export as as a quicktime movie and then convert that to an AVI.

Answer (score 1):

As @saveenr describes, you can do this in Powerpoint 2013. Unfortunately the quality isn't great if you use the menu option directly but you can relatively easily overcome that with a touch of VBA.

- Open your presentation in PowerPoint 2013
- Press `ALT F11` to open the VBA editor
- Choose `Insert > Module` menu and paste in the code below:

  `'''' Export the current presentation to a mwv movie
   Sub MakeVideo()
     If ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus <> ppMediaTaskStatusInProgress Then
       ActivePresentation.CreateVideo FileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\FromPowerpoint.wmv", _
       UseTimingsAndNarrations:=True, _
       VertResolution:=720, _
       FramesPerSecond:=30, _
       Quality:=100
     Else: MsgBox "There is another conversion to video in progress"
     End If
   End Sub`
- Press `F5` or `Main Menu > Run > Run Sub/Userform` menu item

This will execute the macro which exports a file `fromPowerpoint.wmv` to your desktop. You'll see at the bottom of the main Powerpoint window, in the middle of the status bar, a progress indicator of the export. It's likely to take at least a a few minutes.

The code above exports to 720p resolution. You can change the `720` value about to `1080` for full hd resolution. See [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746354.aspx) for other options (although the documentation is pretty rubbish).

If you want `mp4` output format just change `.wmv` to `.mp4`. I believe the `mp4` is supported from PowerPoint 2013 but this might work with `wmv` in 2010.

(Thanks to [John SR Wilson](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-powerpoint/powerpoint-high-quality-video-export-1080p/cea47417-8b37-4aee-a57a-d589845a1b66) for the code example).